# How to recompile source files?

Tags: android, mobile, android-widget, decompiling, recompile

How to recompile decompiled Android Application files? To be specific, I downloaded these files from here https://code.google.com/p/ubuntu-countdown-widget/ and made the necessary changes by replacing the images, target date, etc.

How to recompile all of these into an `apk` once again, without installing Eclipse and pasting the code all over again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a command-line, call

```
$<your SDK root dir>/tools/android update project -p .
ant (you can append 'debug' here)
```

The apk will be output in ./bin

Comment: I don't know from where & how to access the terminal/command-line. I have Eclipse & Android SDK installed. Could you guide me what to do ? Thanks in Advance.